# Displaying the number of users online and the page they are browsing

Tags: php

When I open the page it returns :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/a1361025/public_html/9/9/functions.php on line 44

and this is line 44

```
echo "$count. ($useronline[ip]) Browsing page: <a href="$useronline[page]">$useronline[page]</a>";
```

Comment: Replace the `"` before and after `$useronline[page]` with `\"`

Comment: if you have any reference you may use this sit http://www.shaddeen.com/posts/read/id-1326397267

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
echo $count . ' (' . $useronline['ip'] . ') Browsing page: <a href="' . $useronline['page'] . '">' . $useronline['page'] . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your quotation marks, if you dont want them to end your string:

```
echo "$count. ($useronline[ip]) Browsing page: <a href=\"$useronline[page]\">$useronline[page]</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You end the string and then paste a variable straight afterwards:

```
echo "$count. ($useronline[ip]) Browsing page: <a href="$useronline[page]">$useronline[page]</a>";
//                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You need to escape them with a backslash (because you use double quotes inside of double quotes):

```
echo "$count. ($useronline[ip]) Browsing page: <a href=\"$useronline[page]\">$useronline[page]</a>";
//                                                     ^                  ^
```